# How to fix 'undefined' object when checking result in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase

so I'm having an issue with a variable(result) that is defined at the top of the code but once I console log it later it returns as undefined. I'm setting up a newsletter form and this is the logic for checking whether the user has already signed up or not, and popping up a message on whether they are.

I've tried to set the variable as a Boolean but the code is checking for a specific user input so that didn't work, I've also tried setting the variable in different parts of the code but no luck. I'm still a novice when it comes to javascript unfortunately.

```
var result = coll.doc(email);
  exists.then(val => {
    console.log(val)
    // perform an action according to existing document or not
    if (val == true) { // document already exists
      alert("already registered to our newsletter. Thank you for your interest!");
      console.log(message)
    } else if (val == false) { // document doesn't exist
      console.log('setting the doc');
      // set the new document
      coll.doc(email).set({
        firstname: firstName,
        lastname: lastName,
        nation: country,
        type: typeofInv
      })
      .then(result => { // if no error
        console.log('Received ticket: ' + result);
        if (result) { // check for certain characteristics in the result here
          alert("You are successfully registered. We will be in touch!");
        }
        console.log(message)
      })
```

The expected results is that the result variable should console log the email that the user input so that I can check certain characteristics against it, but instead I get an undefined result when I console log it. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: We should see how the variable is declared in order to know the scope of that variable. Show more code

Comment: whats is `message` in  `console.log(message)` this is undefined variable

Comment: @CristianTraìna var message = null;

  // check if reference already exists
  var counter = 1;
  var exists = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  coll.get()
  .then((docs) => {
   console.log(docs.size)
    if (docs.size == 0) {
      resolve(false)
      };
    docs.forEach((doc) => {
     if (exists != true) {
       if (doc.id === email) {
        exists = true;
        resolve(exists)
        };
       };
        console.log(counter + " " + docs.size)
        if (counter == docs.size) {
          resolve(false)
        };
        counter += 1;
      });
    })

Comment: @Mr.mb The message variable is defined above the piece of code I posted and it's a boolean I didn't include it because otherwise the piece of code would have been annoyingly long but it looks like this var message = null;

Comment: The above define result and console.log result are the different things. The console.log result it get from it  "then(result =>"

Answer (score 0):

coll.doc(email) may fail and result stay with null value, you should try giving a value to var result before calling coll.doc(email); like this:

```
var whatevervar = "";
```

or if is an int:

```
var whatevervar = 0;
```

of if is a bool:

```
var whatevervar = false;
```

etc...

just like this:

```
var result = "";
result = coll.doc(email);
  exists.then(val => {
    console.log(val)
    // perform an action according to existing document or not
    if (val == true) { // document already exists
      alert("already registered to our newsletter. Thank you for your interest!");
      console.log(message)
    } else if (val == false) { // document doesn't exist
      console.log('setting the doc');
      // set the new document
      coll.doc(email).set({
        firstname: firstName,
        lastname: lastName,
        nation: country,
        type: typeofInv
      })
      .then(result => { // if no error
        console.log('Received ticket: ' + result);
        if (result) { // check for certain characteristics in the result here
          alert("You are successfully registered. We will be in touch!");
        }
        console.log(message)
      })
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply! But I still get it as an undefined variable unfortunately